# Show number of zeros of $z^9+z^5-8z^3+2z+1$ in between $\vert z \vert =1$ and $\vert z \vert = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, roots

So using Rouche's theorem we need to find the number of zeros

$$z^9+z^5-8z^3+2z+1$$

has on $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 1 < \vert z \vert < 2\}$

(i) For $\vert z \vert = 1$ I let the "smaller" function be

$$g(z)=z^9+z^5$$

and my "bigger" or dominating function to be the rest, so

$$f(z) = -8z^3+2z+1$$

and if $\vert z \vert = 1$ we clearly have

$$\vert g(z) \vert \leq \vert f(z) \vert.$$

Then here there's 3 zeroes.

(ii) For $\vert z \vert = 2$, I swapped the big and little thus

$$g(z)=-8z^3+2z+1$$

and

$$f(z) = z^9+z^5$$

which has 9 zeroes and thus inside the annulus we have $9-3=6$ zeros. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your estimates are correct, but for the first part you still have to show that $f(z) = -8z^3+2z+1$ has three zeros in $|z| < 1$.

It becomes a bit simpler if you split the polynomial in
$$
g(z) = z^9+z^5+2z+1 \, , \, f(z) = -8z^3
$$
for the zeros in $|z|< 1$, and in
$$
g(z) = z^5-8z^3+2z+1\, , \, f(z) = z^9
$$
for the zeros in $|z|< 2$.

Comment: Oh I get it, so having a single term in the "bigger" function makes it nicer to tell how many zeroes you actually have without proof? I.e., $-8z^3+2z+1$ has three terms making it harder to see it has $3$ zeros in $\vert z \vert < 1$??

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: Well, it is obvious that $(-8z^3)$ has three zeros in the unit disk, isn't it? And it is not so obvious (at least for me) that all three zeros of $(-8z^3+2z+1)$ are in the unit disk. – Having a monomial as the “bigger term” makes things easier, but of course that is not always possible.

Comment: True, very true. Thanks!! I am preparing for comprehensives in Complex Analysis and am teaching myself before taking the courses.